# Frequent .service file errors occurring

Tags: 11.10, updates

I updated a fresh install of ubuntu 11.10 desktop 32 bit and I am running into frequent errors.

At first I thought they were application specific but now they are occurring randomly.

The line always reads:***"The name [com/org.someapp] was not provided by any .service files"***

There aren't many sources or information on these errors that I can find.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

This are errors by DBus: Some program is requesting a service but there's no application registered to provide it. The value for **[com/org.someapp]** could give a hint on what's missing.

Comment: Thank you Florian, the values are usually 1.15 or 1.17 etc. checking .xsession-errors shows majority of "sender=org.freedesktop.DBus". Should I report a bug somewhere? where would I get the appropriate support?